# Scan-IT to Sheets trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I am using the Add-on Scan-IT to Sheets to input inventory info - I need the function I have coded to run after every scan. The problem is, when the scan is populated to the sheet it does not trigger the onEdit or onChange.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using an installable on edit trigger? The basic trigger will not run if it requires a lot of scopes.

Comment: I have tried, but nothing seems to work any differently than the simple triggers

Answer (score 0):

No trigger activates with a change made by a script or addon. As you can read on [Triggers Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions): «*Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run*». So, it is not possible to use them in your situation.

As a workaround you can use [time triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to run your function, or just run them manually.

Comment: I am trying to create an inventory tracking list that will show real-time numbers - I have settled with a time trigger, however after the script runs I need the 'cursor' to reset to 'A2' and the time trigger will not execute. It only relocates when the script is ran manually `if(checkIn != ''){tCkIn.getRange(sRI,1,checkIn.length,checkIn[0].length).setValues(checkIn)}
  tCkIn.getRange("A1:D").sort(3)
  if(invCk != ''){tInvCk.getRange(sRX,1,invCk.length,invCk[0].length).setValues(invCk)}
  tInvCk.getRange("A1:D").sort(3)
  scan.getRange("A2:L").clear()
  scan.setCurrentCell(start)
  `